# Работа с файлами и структурами. Удалить запись по ее номеру.

Tags: файлы, структуры, c++

Здравствуйте, не знаю как удалить элемент по заданному номеру.
Мы создаем бинарный файл, в консоль заполняем структуру и она записывается в этот новый файл. Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы по номеру который введет пользователь, была удалена соответсв. запись из файла.
У меня не получислось разобраться... 
Вот сама программа:
http://zalil.ru/34576378
не хватает "удаления". Пожалуйста помогите.

---

Здравствуйте, не знаю как удалить элемент по заданному номеру. Мы создаем бинарный файл, в консоль заполняем структуру и она записывается в этот новый файл. Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы по номеру который введет пользователь, была удалена соответсв. запись из файла. У меня не получислось разобраться... Вот сама программа: http://zalil.ru/34576378 не хватает "удаления". 
Пожалуйста помогите.

---

И еще такой нюанс: вот например, удалили запись. Как это показать преподавателю? Ведь в бинарном файле одни иероглифы, как проверить удалилось ли именно то, что должно было? :)

Answer (score 3):

Как правильно решается задача удаления одной записи

1. открываем файл на чтение
2. открываем ещё один файл на запись (новый, с временным именем)
3. счетчик записей = 0
4. пока в входном файле есть записи
5. читаем одну запись
6. увеличиваем счетчик записей на 1
7. если значение счетчика не совпадает с номером нужной записи, то прочитанную запись пишем  в новый файл (иначе  ничего не делаем, тем самым эта запись не попадет в новый файл и по факту будет удалена)
8. конец цикла "пока - строка 4"
9. закрываем оба файла.
10. первый файл удаляем, второй (новый) переименовываем.

Такой алгоритм позволит  работать с файлами произвольного размера. В строке 7 алгоритма можно делать свои условия фильтрации.

> > И еще такой нюанс: вот например, удалили запись. Как это показать преподавателю?

если старый файл не удалять, а к примеру переименовать в "копию", то просто нужно распечатать программой один и другой файл и дать их сличить. При распечатке можно выводить номера записей.

по фразой переименовать в "копию" я понимаю дать просто правильное имя. Если исходный файл данных называется data.dat, то переименовывать можно в data.dat.bak.

Comment: А почему бы не юзать stringstream вместо временного файла?

Comment: по двум причинам.

 1. stringstream для текстовых данных. тогда лучше ifstream/ofstream.
 2. даже если данные держать в памяти - может не хватить ее:). Вот если бы код писался на java/C# - то там только в память. а если ее не хватит - всегда можно полоску докупить :)

Answer (score 3):

Для записей фиксированного размера можно и "по месту" удалять. Открываете файл на чтение-запись. Вычисляете смещения откуда читать и куда писать (исходя из размера записи и ее номера).

Потом в цикле seek, read, seek, write ... до конца файла. После цикла урезаете файл.

Если задать в аргументах смещение и размер удаляемого участка, то требование фиксированного  размера записей уже не нужно.

В общем, примерно так:

```
int
rewrite (FILE *f, off_t to, off_t from, off_t end)
{
  char buf[4096];
  int  l;

  while (from < end) {
    fseek(f, from, SEEK_SET);
    l = fread(buf, 1, 4096, f);
    if (l < 0)
      return l;
    from += l;
    fseek(f, to, SEEK_SET);
    if (fwrite(buf, 1, l, f) != l)
      return -1;
    to += l;
  }

  return l;
}

.....
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r+");
  if (!f)
    fatal(filename);

  struct stat st;
  fstat(fileno(f), &st);
  off_t to = reclen * recno,
    from = to + reclen;
  if (from > st.st_size) {
    printf ("%s size: %ld too small for delete record %d (%d length)\n",
        filename, st.st_size, recno, reclen);
    Usage();
  }

  if (rewrite(f, to, from, st.st_size) < 0)
    fatal("rewrite");

  fflush(f);
  ftruncate(fileno(f), st.st_size - reclen);
  fclose(f);
```